# Using /Carbon, why is time difference between New York and Detroit 0

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

Using /Carbon I'm not getting any time difference between New York timezone and Detroit (or Chicago for that matter) timezone.  I should be getting 60 minutes diff.  Here's the code.

```
    $dtNewYork = \Carbon\Carbon::create(2012, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 'America/New_York');
    $dtDetroit = \Carbon\Carbon::create(2012, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 'America/Detroit');
    $mins = $dtDetroit->diffInMinutes($dtNewYork); 
    echo $mins;
```

$mins is 0.

Answer (score 1):

There is no time difference between Detroit, MI and New York, NY